# AWS VPC Peering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

In a 3-way peering connection A to B and A to C.  **Can A address same instance IP/32 in both B and C via peering connection** - *I  am not sure*. Both B and C have matching /16 CIDRs.

[Routing for Response Traffic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/peering-configurations-partial-access.html#peering-incorrect-response-routing) - simply talks about A sending **responses back** to correct calling instance(in B).

[image]
[image: VPC Peering]

But does not talk about instance in C calling A, neither A calling B or C. What will happen when same /32 from C calls A.

Answer (score 1):

Form the drawing in the reference link that you provided the route table looks like this:

```
Destination Target
172.16.0.0/16   Local
10.0.1.0/24 pcx-aaaabbbb
10.0.0.0/24 pcx-aaaacccc
```

Therefore if Subnet A sends a packet in to an IP address in Subnet B (10.0.1.0/24), it will go to VPC B. Since the two Subnet Bs have overlapping CIDRs the route table will determine the destination. PCX-AAAABBBB has an entry for 10.0.1.0/24.

Instances in VPC C Subnet B will not be able to talk to VPC A as there is no return route back to VPC C. The response for those packets will either be dropped or sent to VPC B Subnet B.

Comment: Thx yes I get this explanation. My core question is: Can A call/address same instance IP/32 in both B and C via peering connection. How ?

Comment: VPC A cannot talk to VPC C Subnet B. There is no route. IF VPC A wants to talk to VPC C Subnet B IP 10.0.1.55 (for example) a "more specific" route could be added: 10.0.1.55/32 pcx-aaaaccc.

Comment: If both VPCs (B and C) have exact same IP 10.0.1.66/32 (as depicted) - how will A talk to both - how will a more specific route resolve the instance?

Comment: Your scenario is not supported by AWS.

Comment: Yes, that would be my general understanding too. So only way maybe is to change the  IP, or eliminate the route completely prevent conflicts